# Sitecore DB: Can't delete Preview DB table from SQL Server 13.0.400

Tags: xdb, sitecore-client, sql-database

I first duplicated the original Sitecore Web DB and just renamed to Sitecore Preview DB.
Now that I noticed I accidentally copied the Sitecore Master DB instead of Web DB and I am trying to delete the current Preview DB but Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio shows an error says "Sitecore_Preview" is currently under use and cannot be deleted.

I tried to stop IIS of the Sitecore instance but it didn't work.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just check the "Close existing connections" checkbox.

[image]